# Calculate "Total" of a column by selecting another column in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am new to PowerBI.
I need to calculate total of "Points" column when i select "Team" column. The table is similar to below:

```
Team    Points 
A1          2
A1          3
A2          1
A3          4
A1          6
A3          3
A3          4
```

I want a calculated column which displays

```
Team     Total Points
A1          11
A2          1
A3          15
```

As i am very new to this, i am not sure how i can go around with this?

Thanks

Comment: In a visual? If you put these columns in a table or matrix visual, it should do this automatically.

Comment: @AlexisOlson yep, got it thank you.